# simplexml_load_string doesn't work with soap response

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the xml response from a soap service. However, I can't get simplexml_load_string to work! Here is my code:

```
//make soap call
objClient = new SoapClient('my-wsdl',
    array('trace' => true,'exceptions' => 0, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
$soapvar = new SoapVar('my-xml', XSD_ANYXML);
$objResponse = $objClient->__soapCall($operation, array($soapvar));

//process result
$str_xml = $objClient->__getLastResponse();
$rs_xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml);
```

...$rs_xml always has just one element with name Envelope.

However, if I use *"print var_export($objClient->__getLastResponse(),true);"* to dump the result to my browser, then cut and paste it into my code as a string variable, it work fine! This is what I mean:

```
$str_xml = 'my cut and pasted xml';
$rs_xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml);
```

So it seems the problem is somehow related to something $objClient->__getLastResponse() is doing to the string it creates... but I'm at a loss as to what the problem is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
$str_xml = $objClient->__getLastResponse();    
$str_xml = strstr($str_xml, '<');
$rs_xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml);
```

As it's a quick and easy hack to strip off stuff before the first opening element.

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work. i've made some progess this morning and it's a namespace issue... almost there!